# Using buttons instead of a text box to pass data asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, button

hi I'm creating a project where the user all the user are running off the same instance using the singleton design pattern.  when user types a value into a textbox. It will then wait until everyone else has type a value and then display the results. My question is can this be done using buttons that send a value to the model instead of a textbox. e.g. multiple buttons each one sending a different value.

Heres my code now.

view

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Voting";
     }
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<fieldset>
    <div class="editor-label">
       What is you vote?
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBox("Vote")
    </div>



    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
     }
```

controller

```
         public ActionResult PlanVote()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PlanVote(int vote)
    {
        PlanModel myModel = PlanModel.Instance;
        myModel.Vote(vote);

        if (PlanModel.Instance.currentstate == PlanState.displaying)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Plan");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Waiting", "Plan");
        }
     }
```

model

```
    public void Vote(int Votes)
    {

        countVotes++;
        ivote.Add(Votes);

        if (countVotes >= iCount)
        {
            currentstate = PlanState.displaying;
        }


    }
```

I'm still Quite new to MVC and would be great-full for any help thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove stand alone submit button and use one submit per vote

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<fieldset>
    <div class="editor-label">
       What is you vote?
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input type="submit" name="vote" value="1" />
        <input type="submit" name="vote" value="2" />
        <input type="submit" name="vote" value="3" />
    </div>
</fieldset>
}
```